# Async each in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I tried to use async `#each` loop in svelte and found it it runs synchronously no matter what, using async await function like this:

```
{#each items as item (item.id)}
    {#await render(item) then source}
        <Canvas {source} />
    {:catch}
        <p>error</p>
    {/await}
{/each}
```

and found it there is no way to use async component in svelte cause onmount can't be used asynchronously like this:

```
{#each items as item (item.id)}
    <Canvas {item} />
{/each}
```

is there any workaround this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment it sounds like you are having trouble updating elements in the array using async. Here is an example initializing in `onMount` using an async function, and then rerendering using the `immutable` flag to only update those elements that have changed. This example puts all the promise handling in the script rather than in the jsx.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/14c5f3c772244458b1618058107fc6c9?version=3.44.3)

```
// App.svelte
<svelte:options immutable={false} />

<script>
    import Item from "./Item.svelte";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    let array;

    const sleep = async (ms) => await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));

    async function render(id) {
        await sleep(800);
        array = array.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === id) {
                return {
                    ...item,
                    render: item.render + 1,
                };
            }
            return item;
        });
    }

    onMount(() => {
        async function init() {
            array = await Promise.all(
                [...Array.from({ length: 5 }).keys()].map((i) =>
                    Promise.resolve({
                        id: i + 1,
                        name: `item_${i + 1}`,
                        render: 0,
                    })
                )
            );
        }

        init();

        return () => console.log("destroyed");
    });
</script>

{#if array && array.length}
    {#each array as item (item.id)}
        <Item {item} on:click={() => render(item.id)} />
    {/each}
{/if}
```

```
// ./Item.svelte
<svelte:options immutable={true} />

<script>
    import { afterUpdate } from "svelte";
    
    export let item;
</script>

<div>
    <p>
        {item.name} [render: {item.render}]
    </p>
    <button on:click>render</button>
</div>
```

But you could also incorporate an `{#await}` block to handle an array of promises in the jsx. (It uses the same `Item` component as above)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b5ad95369aea4e20981cabd84fa0cbd1?version=3.44.3)

```
// App.svelte
<svelte:options immutable={false} />

<script>
    import Item from "./Item.svelte";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    let array;

    async function render(id) {
        array = await Promise.all(
            array.map(async (promiseItem) => {
                if (promiseItem.id === id) {
                    const _item = await promiseItem.item;
                    return {
                        id: promiseItem.id,
                        item: new Promise((r) =>
                            setTimeout(() => r({ ..._item, render: _item.render + 1,}), 800)
                        ),
                    };
                }
                return promiseItem;
            })
        );
    }

    onMount(() => {
        async function init() {
            array = [...Array.from({ length: 5 }).keys()].map((i) => ({
                id: i,
                item: Promise.resolve({
                    id: i + 1,
                    name: `item_${i + 1}`,
                    render: 0,
                }),
            }));
        }

        init();

        return () => console.log("destroyed");
    });
</script>

{#if array && array.length}
    {#each array as { id, item: promise } (id)}
        {#await promise}
            <p>...rendering</p>
        {:then item}
            <Item {item} on:click={() => render(item.id)} />
        {/await}
    {/each}
{/if}
```

---

**Original answer**

You haven't really made it clear what isn't working. You *can* run async calls in `onMount` and await the promises in an `{#await}` block.

Here's a contrived [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3ed6cbe13630427f9a063281110dc120?version=3.44.3) that builds an array of promises, uses `Promise.all` to resolve them and assigns the the resulting promise to variable to be rendered.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    let promise;

    async function render(i) {
        return {
            id: i + 1,
            name: `item_${i + 1}`,
        };
    }

    onMount(() => {
        const array = [...Array.from({length: 5}).keys()];
        promise = Promise.all(array.map((i) => render(i)));

        return () => console.log("destroyed");
    });
</script>

{#await promise}
    <p>...rendering</p>
{:then array}
    {#if array && array.length}
        {#each array as item (item.id)}
            <p>
                {item.name}
            </p>
        {/each}
    {/if}
{:catch error}
    <p>oh dear.</p>
{/await}
```

Comment: I already tried a similar approach using stores and i don’t wanna lose reactivity upon updating the array hence it will reload all of the items/images again every time hence currently it only reloads the updated item only but my problem is it doesn’t load them ordered initially.

Comment: It Works! .. not what i exactly had in mind cause now it preloads all the images but it kept the order, i'll try to figure out away to fix that later.

Comment: Is there any way to render them one by one in order not with promise all! just to show the rendered first and move to the next one?

Comment: Nevermind i finally did it, thank you :)